# Possible integer overflow in constraint: linear

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

Dears, I'm using CP-SAT in python.
I have two variables:

```
pippo = model.NewIntVar(-93372036854775808,9123372036854775807, 'pippo')
test = model.NewIntVar(-93372036854775808,9123372036854775807, 'test')
```

and the following decision variables:

```
for r in self.all_records:
            memory = {}
            for p in self.all_decisions:
                # create bool decision variables
                memory[p] = model.NewBoolVar('c' + str(r) + self.scenario.decisions[p].name)
            self.decision_var[r] = memory
```

I have two constraints:

```
1) test==sum(self.scenario.dataset['is_fraud'][r]*self.decision_var[r][0] for r in self.all_records)

2) pippo == test
```

If I remove constraint 2) everything is ok, but with constraint 2 I get this error:

```
Possible integer overflow in constraint: linear {
  vars: 126660
  vars: 126661
  coeffs: -1
  coeffs: 1
  domain: 0
  domain: 0
}
and Status is MODEL_INVALID.
```

I really do not understand why. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solver pro-actively checks for possible overflow.
If the model has a potential integer overflow, it is deemed invalid.

You are seeing this message. Please reduce the bounds of the integer variables (int32 min/max is most likely enough).

Comment: is there a way to avoid this pre-check? I meant to not execute it

Comment: No, the solver is not robust in that case. So the solution will most likely be invalid. But you can call the validate method before solving.